# How to find errors in large Eclipse program

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, exception

I've got a rather large program that interacts with a MySQL database. I recently changed the structure of the database considerably, but I thought I had made all of the necessary changes to my program to compensate for those database changes, but clearly I haven't.

I just recently several error messages, the first of which is this:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
```

Strangely, though, it doesn't give tell me in which file this error came from (as a typical stacktrace would), let alone on which line number. How can I figure out from where this is coming?

I have a lot of calls to the database in this program, most of which deal with a Timestamp column. And I'm afraid that, while I have been using Eclipse for months now, I still have yet to use its Debug perspective. How can I use that?

Comment: This is where unit and integration testing help you.

Comment: First thing to do: fix your logging. You haven't told us anything about the app or what's logging it, but there's no reason why it *shouldn't* be producing a full stack trace...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the constructor of SQLException, and start your program in debug mode. Use the app until it goes to the breakpoint. The stack will tell you which code causes the exception to be created.

Comment: Using a bunch of `System.out.println`s and log4j, I was able to trace where the problem originated. It turned out that most of the records in my MySQL database table had `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as a Timestamp, which is apparently impossible. I'm not sure how it happened, but since that column could be set to `NULL`, I just changed them to that, instead.

As for breakpoints, it seems like they never work for me. I've tried using them before and they just disappear without pausing execution of the code. I guess I just don't know how to use them properly.